# libreoffice 4.2.8 go extremely hard working with images embedded

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice go extremely hard working with images embedded in Ubuntu 14.04 Writer LibreOffice 4.2.8

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable displaying images in Writer: Menu "Options" -> "LibreOffice Writer" -> "View" -> "Display" - untick "Graphics and objects".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I went off even better graphics, but I want the images to see them ... LibreOffice Writer 3.5 runs very well with images inserted into the document. I noticed that LibreOffice 4.2 and 5.1 of the inserted picture Writer hard going. I believe they have a bug.